# how to pass credentials to rename command?

Tags: powershell

I'm running the following command in a PowerShell script to simply rename a computer.  The script will be executed by a computer startup script GPO, so I need to pass credentials within the command.  As I can't see what's happening with the script if it's executed at startup I'm testing it by running the script while logged on as a normal user

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Rename( $NewName,'Password','domain\username')
```

The command returns a ReturnValue of '5' - Access Denied.  How can I pass the username and password?  (I understand the security risk regarding a password in the script)

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ReturnValue      : 5
PSComputerName   :
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're always running this on the same machine or the associated account roams then IIRC you can rely on DPAPI to store the key like so:

```
# Capture once and store to file
$passwd = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$encpwd = ConvertFrom-SecureString $passwd
$encpwd
$encpwd > $path\password.bin

# Later pull this in and restore to a secure string
$encpwd = Get-Content $path\password.bin
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $encpwd

# Extract a plain text password from secure string
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($passwd)
$str =  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($bstr)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)
$str
```

If that doesn't work, you can use this approach but it not as secure as the above approach:

```
$key = 1..32 | ForEach-Object { Get-Random -Maximum 256 }
$passwd = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$encpwd = ConvertFrom-SecureString $passwd -Key $key
$encpwd

# Could easily modify this to store username also
$record = new-object psobject -Property @{Key = $key; EncryptedPassword = $encpwd}
$record
$record | Export-Clixml $path\portablePassword.bin

# Later pull this in and restore to a secure string
$record = Import-Clixml $path\portablePassword.bin
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $record.EncryptedPassword -Key $record.Key

# Extract a plain text password from secure string
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($passwd)
$str =  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($bstr)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)
$str
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the following [here](http://www.hofferle.com/rename-computers-with-powershell/):

```
$credential = Get-Credential
Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName OLDNAME -Authentication 6 |
ForEach-Object {$_.Rename("NEWNAME",$credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password,$credential.Username)}
```

It looks like you need to set the authentication level to be able to pass credentials (optionally using the Get-Credential CMDLet).  I'm afraid I haven't got a box available to test this on at the moment.