# Powershell - Pass credentials

Tags: powershell

Part 2 of an earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992772/powershell-secure-credentials) - I know have a variable which contains a password in plaintext, and a username in plaintext which happens to be a email address. I need to use these in order to send an email via SMTP in powershell, Send-MailMessage for example.

So I need to pass it:

`personx@persony.com` and `$password`

In order to authenticate against a smart host the send the email. Any way of doing this, something clever with Get-Credential or some switch on Send-MailMessage, or is there another totally different option?

Cheers

Comment: quick search gives this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password   . check out the line starting With `$cred` and supply it to send-mailmessage -credential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ConvertTo-SecureString` to convert your plain text password.

Assuming your username is in `$username` variable and plain text password in `$password`, you can do something like this:

```
$securepass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -String $password -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,$securepass

Send-MailMessage ... -Credentials $creds
```