# Entering a password for DomainCredential in Rename-Computer in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, mdt

I am trying to use a Powershell script to rename computers based on their serial numbers.

So far I have -
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Unrestricted
$name = (Get-WmiObject win32_bios).SerialNumber.Trim()
Rename-Computer -NewName $name -DomainCredential \

I don't want this to prompt because I have a few thousand system to image and I would like this to just do the rename silently and then the MDT 2012 Update 1 will do the reboot.

I am a n00b when it comes to powershell and to scripting and I have spent the better part of a week trying to figure this out.  I can get the rename to work locally with no problems but I am hoping I can get some help doing it silently.

I guess my question is, how do I put a password in my powershell script so I don't have to enter it at the workstation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Get-WmiObject` command let for the same and pass a password stored in a variable like below

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Rename( $NewName,$passwd,'domain\username')
```

to store the password in variable, you can do something like

```
$key = 1..32 | ForEach-Object { Get-Random -Maximum 256 }
$passwd = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$encpwd = ConvertFrom-SecureString $passwd -Key $key
$encpwd
```

This examples are taken from this post [how to pass credentials to rename command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842611/how-to-pass-credentials-to-rename-command)

go through this post; it explains both secure and non-secure way of storing the password in great detail.

Comment: This helps a lot, Thank you.  I will testing and tweaking this today.

Comment: Done, I really appreciate your help on this.  I was able to get it working.  I can't give you an up arrow because I am new to this community.

Comment: @Fridflenstone, Glad to help you. That's alright and I understand. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late, but couldn't you do: OSDComputerName=%serialnumber% in your task sequence rules since you're using MDT?

When the task sequence runs it should just set the computer name to that serial number. If you had a prefix or suffix like OSDComputerName=WS%SerialNumber%

Comment: For some reason when I set that my custom settings.INI it just gets ignored. As it turns out our WDS server went belly up.  We will be re building the sever tomorrow and I will try this again as it will be the simplest option.